# QuickBooks: Invalid Reference Id : Accounts element id 725 not found

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am integrating my service with QuickBooks and get this error:
`QuickBooks: Invalid Reference Id : Accounts element id 725 not found.`

Did anyone have it or knows why does this happen?
I got it once and now cannot repeat it: maybe any ideas on how to recreate it?

Answer (score 0):

Missing information of what you intended to do.
But in any case, **Account** could be missing at that moment.

Recommendation: if that is not reproducing - maybe it is not an error ;)
But in any case, there can be errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the ACCOUNT documentation on Intuit Developer:
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/account

You can try to QUERY the ACCOUNT.

**Sample Request URL & Sample Query:**

```
GET /v3/company/<realmID>/query?query=<selectStatement>

Content type:text/plain
Production Base URL:https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com
Sandbox Base URL:https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com
```

```
select * from Account where Metadata.CreateTime > '2014-12-31'
```